# Can't use mlpackages when making a React Native NPM Package

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, coreml

I am trying to create a react-native-vision-camera frame processor packaged as a NPM package just like the examples [here](https://www.react-native-vision-camera.com/docs/guides/frame-processor-plugin-list). I am trying to use some .mlpackage files from CoreML that I compiled from some models I made. Whenever I try and test the package I get errors that look like "cannot find 'ModelName' in scope". I dragged in the mlpackages and made sure they generated their classes in both the package xcproject and in the example app I'm using to test. I also made sure in both the package and example app that the target's build settings coreML model class generation language is set correctly and inherit NSObject is set to yes.

Here is a picture of my .xcproject: [image: XCode]

Here is the code of my frame processor plugin:

```
//
//  ML-Frame=Processor.swift
//  CardScannerMobile
//
//  Created by Carl Schader on 2/25/23.
//

import Accelerate
import Foundation
import CoreML
import CoreImage
import Vision

public func readLabels() throws -> [Int]? {
  if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "labels", ofType: "json") {
    do {
      let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
      let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves)
      if let jsonResult = jsonResult as? [Int] {
        print("labels loaded")
        return jsonResult
      }
    } catch {
      print("error loading labels")
      print(error.localizedDescription)
      throw error
    }
  }
  return nil
}

extension CGImage {
  func resize(size:CGSize) -> CGImage? {
    let width: Int = Int(size.width)
    let height: Int = Int(size.height)

    let bytesPerPixel = self.bitsPerPixel / self.bitsPerComponent
    let destBytesPerRow = width * bytesPerPixel


    guard let colorSpace = self.colorSpace else { return nil }
    guard let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: self.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: destBytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: self.alphaInfo.rawValue) else { return nil }

    context.interpolationQuality = .high
    context.draw(self, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))

    return context.makeImage()
  }
}

public func cropPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer, rect: CGRect, size: CGSize, context: CIContext) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
  let ciImageDepth = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
  let cgImageDepth:CGImage = context.createCGImage(ciImageDepth, from: ciImageDepth.extent)!
  guard let croppedImage = cgImageDepth.cropping(to: rect) else {
    return nil
  }
  
  guard let resizedImage = croppedImage.resize(size: size) else {
    return nil
  }
  
  return resizedImage.pixelBuffer()
}

@objc(CardInferencePlugin)
public class CardInferencePlugin: NSObject, FrameProcessorPluginBase {
  private static let ciContext = CIContext()
  
  private static let yoloShape: [NSNumber] = [3, 640, 640]
  private static let yoloPixelBuffer = createPixelBuffer(width: yoloShape[1].intValue, height: yoloShape[2].intValue)
  
  private static let siameseShape: [NSNumber] = [3, 320, 320]
  private static var siamesePixelBuffer = createPixelBuffer(width: siameseShape[1].intValue, height: siameseShape[2].intValue)
  
  private static let embeddingSize: NSNumber = 128
  
  private static let yoloModel = try! YoloNMS(configuration: MLModelConfiguration())
  private static let siameseModel = try! Siamese(configuration: MLModelConfiguration())
  private static let classifierModel = try! Classifier(configuration: MLModelConfiguration())
  
  private static let labelArray = try! readLabels()
  
  private static var previousBoxes = [[Float]]()
  private static var previousTrackingNumbers = [Int]()
  private static var boxTrackingNumber: Int = 0
  
  @objc
  public static func callback(_ frame: Frame!, withArgs args: [Any]!) -> Any! {
    let buffer = frame.buffer
    //    let orientation = frame.orientation
    
    guard let originalPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(buffer!) else {
      print("error getting pixel buffer")
      return nil
    }
    
    if let yoloPixelBuffer = yoloPixelBuffer { resizePixelBuffer(originalPixelBuffer, width: Int(truncating: yoloShape[1]), height: Int(truncating: yoloShape[2]), output: yoloPixelBuffer, context: ciContext) }
    
    var yoloPreds: YoloNMSOutput
    do {
      try yoloPreds = yoloModel.prediction(input: YoloNMSInput(image: yoloPixelBuffer!, iouThreshold: 0.45, confidenceThreshold: 0.5))
    } catch {
      return error.localizedDescription
    }
    
    let originalHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(originalPixelBuffer)
    let originalWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(originalPixelBuffer)
    
    var siamesePreds: MLMultiArray
    do {
      try siamesePreds = MLMultiArray(shape: [0, embeddingSize], dataType: MLMultiArrayDataType.float32)
    } catch {
      return error.localizedDescription
    }
    
    var boxes = [[Float]]()
    for i in 0..<yoloPreds.confidence.count {
      let row = i * 4
      let x = yoloPreds.coordinates[row].floatValue
      let y = yoloPreds.coordinates[row + 1].floatValue
      let width = yoloPreds.coordinates[row + 2].floatValue
      let height = yoloPreds.coordinates[row + 3].floatValue
      boxes.append([x, y, width, height])
      
      let cropX = Int((x - (width / 2)) * Float(originalWidth))
      let cropY = Int((y - (height / 2)) * Float(originalHeight))
      let cropWidth = Int(width * Float(originalWidth))
      let cropHeight = Int(height * Float(originalHeight))
      
      guard let croppedBuffer = cropPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer: originalPixelBuffer, rect: CGRect(x: cropX, y: cropY, width: cropWidth, height: cropHeight), size: CGSize(width: siameseShape[1].intValue, height: siameseShape[2].intValue), context: ciContext) else {
        print("Error cropping pixel buffer")
        return nil
      }
      
      do {
        try siamesePreds = MLMultiArray(concatenating: [siamesePreds, siameseModel.prediction(input: SiameseInput(image: croppedBuffer)).embeddings], axis: 0, dataType: MLMultiArrayDataType.float32)
      } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
      }
    }
    
    if (siamesePreds.shape[0] == 0) {
      return nil
    }
    
    guard labelArray != nil else {
      print("labels not loaded")
      return nil
    }
    
    var labels = [Int]()
    do {
      let preds = try classifierModel.prediction(input: ClassifierInput(embeddings: siamesePreds)).indexes
      for i in 0..<preds.count {
        labels.append(labelArray![preds[i].intValue])
      }
    } catch {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
      return nil
    }
    
//    Object tracking O(n^2)
    let squareDistanceThreshold: Float = 0.01
    var indexMap: [Int] = Array(repeating: -1, count: previousBoxes.count)
    var distanceMap: [Float] = Array(repeating: Float.infinity, count: previousBoxes.count)
    for i in 0..<previousBoxes.count {
      for j in 0..<boxes.count {
        let xdiff = boxes[j][0] - previousBoxes[i][0]
        let ydiff = boxes[j][1] - previousBoxes[i][1]
        let squareDistance = (xdiff * xdiff) + (ydiff * ydiff)
        if squareDistance <= squareDistanceThreshold && squareDistance < distanceMap[i] {
          indexMap[i] = j
          distanceMap[i] = squareDistance
        }
      }
    }
    
    var newTrackingNumbers = [Int]()
    for _ in 0..<boxes.count {
      newTrackingNumbers.append(boxTrackingNumber)
      boxTrackingNumber = boxTrackingNumber &+ 1
    }
    
    for i in 0..<indexMap.count {
      if indexMap[i] != -1 {
        newTrackingNumbers[indexMap[i]] = previousTrackingNumbers[i]
      }
    }
    previousTrackingNumbers = newTrackingNumbers
    previousBoxes = boxes
    
    return ["boxes": boxes, "labels": labels, "trackingNumbers": newTrackingNumbers]
    
//
//    let tuples = boxes.enumerated().map { (index, element) in
//      return (element, labels[index])
//    }
//    let sorted = tuples.sorted {
//      ($0.0[0] * $0.0[0]) + ($0.0[1] * $0.0[1]) < ($1.0[0] * $1.0[0]) + ($1.0[1] * $1.0[1])
//    }
//
//    return ["boxes": sorted.map { $0.0 }, "labels": sorted.map { $0.1 }]
    
////    No object tracking
//    return ["boxes": boxes, "labels": labels]
  }
}
```

I already tried dragging in the mlpackages and using them as instructed on the CoreML website. This worked for me when I wasn't trying to encapsulate my frame processor as an NPM package and instead it was just a part of the ios folder in the app I'm building. However, it doesn't work when when I try and do it as an NPM package.